# Calculating the Factorial of a number

Tags: java

I am looking for feedback for the implementation for calculating factorial of a number. I have tried to do with a loop, recursion and in a mutlithreaded way.

```
package org.spituk.study.programs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

/**
 * Class for calculating factorial of a number.
 *
 * @author Karan Khanna
 * @version 1.0
 * @since 12/8/2018
 */
public class Factorial {

    private final static int JOB_SIZE = 10;

    private final static int AVAILABLE_PROCESSORS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    /**
     * Calculates the factorial of the number with loop.
     *
     * @param number whose factorial is to be calculated.
     * @return calculated factorial of the number
     */
    public long getFactorialWithLoop(final int number) {
        long factorial = 1;
        for (int index = 2; index <= number; index++) {
            factorial = factorial * index;
        }
        return factorial;
    }


    /**
     * Calculates the factorial of the number with recursion.
     *
     * @param number whose factorial is to be calculated.
     * @return calculated factorial of the number
     */
    public long getFactorialWithRecursion(final int number) {
        return factorialRecursion(number);
    }


    /**
     * Calculates the factorial of the number with multiple threads.
     *
     * @param number whose factorial is to be calculated.
     * @return calculated factorial of the number
     */
    public long getFactorialMultiThreaded(final int number) throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(AVAILABLE_PROCESSORS);
        List<PartialFactorialJob> partialFactorialJobs = new ArrayList<PartialFactorialJob>();

        int startIndex = 1;
        int pivot = JOB_SIZE;

        while(pivot <= number) {
            if(pivot + JOB_SIZE > number) {
                pivot = number;
            }
            partialFactorialJobs.add(new PartialFactorialJob(startIndex, pivot));
            startIndex = pivot + 1;
            pivot = pivot + JOB_SIZE;
        }

        try {
            long factorial = 1;
            final List<Future<Long>> futureList = executor.invokeAll(partialFactorialJobs);
            for (Future<Long> future : futureList) {
                factorial = factorial * future.get();
            }
            executor.shutdown();
            return factorial;
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new Exception("Factorial couldn't be calculated.");
        }
    }


    private long factorialRecursion(final int number) {
        if (number <= 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return number * factorialRecursion(number - 1);
    }

    private class PartialFactorialJob implements Callable<Long> {

        private final int startIndex;
        private final int endIndex;

        PartialFactorialJob(final int startIndex, final int endIndex) {
            this.startIndex = startIndex;
            this.endIndex = endIndex;
        }

        public Long call() {
            long partialFactorial = 1;
            int temp = startIndex;
            while (temp <= endIndex) {
                partialFactorial = partialFactorial * temp;
                temp++;
            }
            return partialFactorial;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you are asking for? (I don't understand)

Comment: A review for the code.

Comment: Ok! I thought to be in stackoverflow, excuse me!

Comment: What is the purpose of the multi-threaded version? Keep in mind that for `number >= 66` the result is always zero

Answer (score 4):

A few comments:

---

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
```

Never do wildcard imports unless you're doing a one-time, throw-away program. Maybe, in Java 20 or so, they introduce a class `java.util.concurrent.Factorial` (contrived example), and then you have a name collision with one of your classes. Better stick to individual imports (or have your IDE organize the imports).

---

Thumbs up for attaching javadoc to all public elements.

---

```
public long getFactorialWithRecursion(final int number) {
    return factorialRecursion(number);
}
```

I'd skip the indirection from `getFactorialWithRecursion()` calling `factorialRecursion()` and write

```
public long getFactorialWithRecursion(final int number) {
    if (number <= 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return number * getFactorialWithRecursion(number - 1);
}
```

---

Other SO members already commented that computing a factorial with multiple threads might not be a useful application, but I understand that this is for exerecise purposes.

The `while` loop in `getFactorialMultiThreaded` makes it hard to read and understand the code, with the two loop variables `startIndex` and `pivot` having their operations spread over many lines of code. I'd write something like

```
for (int startIndex = 1; startIndex <= number; startIndex += JOB_SIZE) {
    int endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + JOB_SIZE - 1, number);
    partialFactorialJobs.add(new PartialFactorialJob(startIndex, endIndex));
}
```

Similar thing applies to the `while` loop in your `call` method, I'd prefer a `for` loop instead.

---

As your `PartialFactorialJob` class doesn't access anything from the enclosing `Factorial` instance, you should make it static (otherwise it carries around a useless internal reference to its enclosing instance, typically visible in your debugger as `this$1` or similar).

Answer (score 2):

## static

The `Factorial` class doesn't have any non-class data members, so it shouldn't have any non-static methods.

In particular:

1. `getFactorialWithLoop()` can be made `static`.
2. `getFactorialWithRecursion()` can be made `static` if `factorialRecursion()` is also made `static`.
3. `getFactorialMultiThreaded()` can be made `static` if you change `class PartialFactorialJob` to be a `static` inner class.

---

`getFactorialWithLoop()`:

Only change I'd make here would be to use the product-assignment operator.

```
factorial *= index;
```

---

## Tail-Recursion

`getFactorialWithRecusion()` / `factorialRecursion()`:

Since the value returned from a recursive call to `factorialRecursion()` is not directly returned from an outer call, tail-recursion-optimization cannot be performed.  This means the stack can overflow if a deep recursive call is made.  If the value returned from a recursive call is directly returned, tail-recursion-optimization by the compiler can eliminate recursive calls.

```
public long getFactorialWithRecursion(final int number) {
    return factorialRecursion(number, 1);
}

private long factorialRecursion(int number, long accumulator) {
    if (number <= 1)
        return accumulator;
    else
        return factorialRecursion(number - 1, accumulator * number);
}
```

The statement `return factorialRecursion(number - 1, accumulator * number);` can be translated by the compiler into a jump to the start of the function, with modified arguments.

---

## Job-Size

This loop is a no-op for values of `number` less than 10!

```
    int pivot = JOB_SIZE;

    while(pivot <= number) {
        // ...
    }
```

So the multi-threaded factorial does not calculate the result properly for `number < 10`!

The size of a `PartialFactorialJob` can exceed `JOB_SIZE`.  Consider `number = 19`.  `pivot` equals 10, so `pivot + JOB_SIZE > number` is `true`, and `pivot` is assigned `19`, so the first and only job submitted is `new PartialFactorialJob(1, 19)`.

What you want is the while-loop to test for `startIndex` not greater than `number`:

```
int startIndex = 1;

while (startIndex <= number) {
    int endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + JOB_SIZE - 1, number);
    partialFactorialJobs.add(new PartialFactorialJob(startIndex, endIndex));
    startIndex += JOB_SIZE;
}
```

But now this looks like a for-loop:

```
for (startIndex = 1; startIndex <= number; startIndex += JOB_SIZE) {
    int endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + JOB_SIZE - 1, number);
    partialFactorialJobs.add(new PartialFactorialJob(startIndex, endIndex));
}
```

---

## Argument Limits

`21!` exceeds the size of a `long`.  You might want:

```
if (number < 0 || number > 20)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Factorial out-of-range")
```

Or you may want to use `BigInteger` for calculation of larger factorials.

---

## Bonus Methods

You can also use the Stream API to calculate factorials:

```
long getFactorialWithStream(final int number) {
    return LongStream.rangeClosed(1, number)
                     .reduce(1, (x,y) -> x*y);
}

long getFactorialWithParallelStream(final int number) {
    return LongStream.rangeClosed(1, number)
                     .parallel()
                     .reduce(1, (x,y) -> x*y);
}
```